# Get index of second non-alphanumeric

Tags: c#, regex

So I'm trying to sanitize some text chunks. I thought that `regex` might be a nice solution rather than having a bunch of `if` statemement. But alas I'm not that good with the regex expressions. So I hoped that some of you guys might be willing to help me.

**The case**
I have different text which needs to be formattet

```
string one = "tbEmails";
string two = "dbo.tbEmails";
string three = "dbo.tbEmails,\n\t";
string four = "dbo.tbEmails.";
```

The result I'm looking for is

```
one = "tbEmails";
two = "dbo.tbEmails";
three = "dbo.tbEmails";
four = "dbo.tbEmails";
```

I know that I can get the index of the first non-alphanumeric value by using

```
int index = new Regex("[^a-zA-Z ]").Match("dbo.tbEmails,\n\t").Index;
```

But how can I ignore the first `.` in the regex and get the index of the second non-alphanumeric value. And as a bonus: is there a way to return the first non-alphanumeric value in case there's no `.` in the string?

Comment: You may get all matches and get the data you need from the `match[1]`. But it seems you just need `Regex.Replace(str, @"(?s)^([^\W_]+(?:[\W_][^\W_]+)?).*", "$1");`, see [demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%28%5b%5e%5cW_%5d%2b%28%3f%3a%5b%5cW_%5d%5b%5e%5cW_%5d%2b%29%3f%29.*&i=tbEmails%0d%0adbo.tbEmails%0d%0adbo.tbEmails%2c%0d%0adbo.tbEmails.&r=%241&o=m).

Comment: How about `string.Trim()`?

Comment: It seems like you have stated the problem to yourself in a much more complicated way, or you have given an example that is much simpler than what you're trying to do.

Comment: @Kir: gotta be the first, seeing Wiktor's suggestion I've realized how simple the solution really is. Amazing how easily one can end up overlooking the solution ;-)

Comment: If you have a predefined set of split-chars you could also use: `one = String.Join(".", one.Split({'.', ','}, 3).Take(2));`. That works with your samples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, to get an Nth match index, just use `Regex.Matches` to find all the matches and check if the item with the necessary index can be accessed, and if yes, get the details you need from the Match object:

```
var index = -1; 
var matches = Regex.Matches(str, @"[^a-zA-Z ]");
if (matches.Count > 1)  // at least 2
{
    index = matches[1].Index;
}
```

BTW, a non-alphanumeric pattern is `[\W_]`, and an alphanumeric is `[^\W_]` (or `[\w-[_]]`).

It also seems that you may use a regex replace operation to get the results you seek with

```
Regex.Replace(str, @"(?s)^([^\W_]+(?:[\W_][^\W_]+)?).*", "$1");
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5E%28%5B%5E%5CW_%5D%2B%28%3F%3A%5B%5CW_%5D%5B%5E%5CW_%5D%2B%29%3F%29.%2A&i=tbEmails%0D%0Adbo.tbEmails%0D%0Adbo.tbEmails%2C%0D%0Adbo.tbEmails.&r=%241&o=m)

Or a simpler matching regex:

```
var match = Regex.Match(str, @"^[^\W_]+(?:[\W_][^\W_]+)?");
if (match.Success) 
{
    Console.Write(match.Value);
}
```

**Details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `[^\W_]+` - 1 or more alphanumeric chars
- `(?:[\W_][^\W_]+)?` - 1 or 0 occurrences of:

  - `[\W_]` - 1 char other than an alphanumeric char
  - `[^\W_]+` - 1 or more alphanumeric chars

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have stated the problem to yourself in a much more complicated way, or you have given an example that is much simpler than what you're trying to do.

If you are trying to remove unwanted characters from the beginning and end of your strings, then you can do  myString.Trim('\n','.'). If you don't know the concrete set of chars you're trying to remove, you may do this:

`Regex.Replace(str, "[^\\w]*$","");`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this RegEx to get your match directly:

```
string value = new Regex("[A-Za-z ]+(?:[^A-Za-z ][A-Za-z ]+)?").Match("dbo.tbEmails,\n\t").Value;
```

The term `[A-Za-z ]+` matches all [A-Za-z ] characters until the first non [A-Za-z ] character. `(?:[^A-Za-z ][A-Za-z ]+)` matches the first other character and all [A-Za-z ] characters until the second other character. The `?` makes the second part conditional.